# Execute python script on Jenkins with variables

Tags: python, jenkins

I have created a job in Jenkins, for which user provides the value of a specific parameter, let's say PYTHON_PARM, as an input. On this job I execute a python script (using Python Plugin). The problem is that I want to use as a variable the user input $PYTHON_PARM parameter. This is not considered as an environment variable, so when trying to use os.environ['PYTHON_PARM'], this doesn't work.
Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please provide more detail to add context to the question? Maybe a code snippet or error

Comment: Job's slave is a windows pc, so I'm trying through a batch to set the user's input in a variable:
Execute Windows batch command:
set TYPE = %Type%, 

Then try to retrieve it in python scipt:
Execute Python script:
Type = os.environ['TYPE']

The error I'm getting is:
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\Users\ipsl\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson6045045489072241428.py", line 67, in <module>
    Type = os.environ['TYPE']
File "C:\Users\ipsl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TYPE'

Thanks @minocha

Comment: Do you use a freestyle job or a Pipeline one?

Comment: It is a freestyle job.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
from os import environ

Type = environ['Type']

Comment: Still no answer here?